# After running my code, a "none" appears after the integer response

Tags: python

```
def dotProduct(listA, listB):
    assert len(listA) == len(listB)
    listC = []
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(listA)):
        listC.append(listA[i]*listB[i])
        sum += listA[i]*listB[i]
    #return sum
    print (sum)

dotProduct([1,2,3], [4,5,6])    
dotProduct([1, 58, -31, -73, -85, 26, 15, -42], [88, 73, -98, -51, 54, -45, -59, -30])
```

Why does my code constantly print none after the integer answer? I have no return statements or additional print statements

Comment: Python functions return `None` if no other value is explicitly returned. How are you running this code? It is possible that something is automatically printing out the return value of the function in addition to any `print()` calls.

Comment: Uncomment the `#return sum` and see what happens.

Comment: You're very likely running this in a shell, which outputs the return value of the function, None. I can reproduce this behaviour in the IDLE interactive shell and the python 3.7.3 and 3.9.1 shells on Windows. This behaviour should be true in most modern REPLs.

Comment: thank you for your help! I am starting out in programming and didn't realize there were differences in running the code in a shell vs. console. I now understand where I went wrong